# Custom keywords in Spotlight plugin for Mac OS X

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, spotlight

I am developing a Spotlight plugin for PSD files that can search in the text of the PSD file also. I want to add the `kind:` keyword to the plugin to narrow the search results.

My question is: Can we add a custom `kind:` keyword to Spotlight plugins? If yes, will they work in the same manner as the default keywords?

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking. I think by `kind:` you're referring to the `kMDItemKind` metadata attribute.

If so, then yes, you can definitely expose this in your Spotlight importer. You can expose any of the [standard metadata keys](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/MetadataAttributesRef/Reference/CommonAttrs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001694-SW1) or [define new ones of your own](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/MDImporters/Concepts/AssigningDataToAttrs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001837-221562).